# TypeCast Exception while running Pig Script

Tags: hive, apache-pig

Below is my pig script. Its very straightforward. Loading some data. Filtering the data by a column. Generating the schema with datatypes. Storing the data in a hive table.
When I am executing the data, its throwing

```
emp = load '/root/emp.nulls' using PigStorage(',');
filt = filter emp by $2 is not null;
f = foreach filt generate $0 as id:int, $1 as bdate:chararray, $2 as fname:chararray, $3 as lname:chararray, $4 as gender:chararray, $5 as hdate:chararray;
store f into 'emp_null' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

When I am executing the data, its throwing the below error

```
2017-09-15 11:21:04,523 [Thread-12] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1554819907_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.StoreFuncDecorator.putNext(StoreFuncDecorator.java:83)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map.collect(PigMapOnly.java:48)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:282)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:275)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Can someone help me?

EDIT:
If I generate the schema during loading itself, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the following syntax  `$0 as id:int` you are not casting the field but using a new field to store the value in $0.The correct way to do this is to prefix the datatype in front of the field.This might have been fixed in the newer versions of Pig.Here is the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2315) being discussed to fix it.

```
f = foreach filt generate (int)$0 as id, 
                          (chararray)$1 as bdate,
                          (chararray)$2 as fname, 
                          (chararray)$3 as lname, 
                          (chararray)$4 as gender, 
                          (chararray)$5 as hdate;
```